# Quick CSS hover question

Tags: css, hover, tumblr

James here. I have a quick question. I want to add a similar image hover affect like on http://themaxdavis.com , but for some reason I can't quite get it. I want to add to my code when you hover over the picture post (.pic), a black overlay with a 0.5 opacity to fade in over the image itself. Also, if anyone could help me figure out a way to put text inside that black overlay also like Max Davis, that would be AWESOME. Here is the code to the .pic element.

```
.pic { position:relative; overflow: hidden; float: left;
{block:IndexPage}width:250px;{block:IndexPage}
{block:PermalinkPage}width:500px; margin-top: 39px; margin-bottom:
15px;{/block:PermalinkPage} {block:IndexPage}margin: 15px 15px 0px
0px;{/block:IndexPage} background-color: #FFF; z-index: 1;
{block:IndexPage}box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
-webkit-transition: box-shadow 0.3s ease-out;
-moz-transition: box-shadow 0.3s ease-out; transition: box-shadow 0.3s
ease-out;
-o-transition: box-shadow 0.3s ease-out;{block:IndexPage} }
```

My website URL is http://-respawn.tumblr.com

PS I'm on my way out the door now, so I will not accept the answers right away, but I will accept them and read them all as soon as I get home.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cleaned up code:

Assuming that .pic will contain the picture as background or will be an **img** element.

```
.pic
{
    position:relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
    width:250px;
    width:500px;
    margin-top: 39px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    margin: 15px 15px 0px 0px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    z-index: 1;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

Create an empty **div** element inside .pic and give it this style.

```
#emptyDiv
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
    -webkit-transition: box-shadow 0.3s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: box-shadow 0.3s ease-out;
    transition: box-shadow 0.3s ease-out;
    -o-transition: box-shadow 0.3s ease-out;
}
#emptyDiv:hover
{
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

Comment: @james, show me an URL with a demonstration and I will tell you why it does not work.